# Ember.js, Performances, Performances: <button onclick=(action 'someAction')> VS <button {{action 'someAction'}}>

Tags: javascript, performance, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

In this amazing video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=udix3GZouik) Alex Blom talks about "hacks" in Ember for mobile world.

At 22:00 he says something about `<button onclick=()>` vs simply `{{action}}`.

[image]

Can you say something more about this? What he really means? Is today still like this?

It works just for `<button>` tag? And for `<a>`?

Answer (score 1):

***For your first question:***

Action helper has two different usage: As normal helper and as closure action.

This usage is closure action usage:

```
<div onclick={{action "save"}}></div>
```

While this is event attachment usage:

```
<div {{action "save"}}></div>
```

***For your second question:***

In the "Specifying DOM event type" section of the ember documentation about [action](https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember/2.14/classes/Ember.Templates.helpers/methods/action?anchor=action) helper, it is described as:

> By default the **{{action}}** helper registers for DOM **click** events.

But if you can override this behaviour by passing `on` parameter as below:

```
<div {{action "anActionName" on="doubleClick"}}>
```

***To read more:***

1. Read the guides about [action helper](https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember/2.14/classes/Ember.Templates.helpers/methods/action?anchor=action)
2. [This](http://miguelcamba.com/blog/2016/01/24/ember-closure-actions-in-depth/) is an excellent blog about closure actions.

Comment: So are you saying that `<div onclick={{action "save"}}></div>` and `<div {{action "save"}}></div>` is the same? Waht is he saying in that video so?

Comment: `<div {{action "save"}}></div>` creates an event handler for `div`. Whereas `<div onclick={{action "save"}}></div>` binds `save` function to the html component's `onclick` event.